# How to deleted duplicated driver profiles in Windows 10?

Tags: windows, windows-10, drivers

[image]

Hi, I am experimenting to modify drivers for my graphic card and unavoidably created a lot of unwanted duplicates. This makes it extremely hard for me to figure out which ones are newly added. I like to know if there is a way to edit the list of the drive profiles and remove them. Thanks.

Comment: http://www.guru3d.com/files-details/display-driver-uninstaller-download.html

Comment: @moab sweet let me give it a try

Comment: Do a manual Windows system restore point before you run that software, just in case.

Comment: @moab I tested it and it did cause some issue. Basically it did a wipe and I had to recover files that was needed. This is why it took me almost a day to reply. I recommand against it. And it didn't really solve the problem...

Comment: @moab yep I didn't read that comment before I went ahead and used it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove the old drivers with [pnputil.exe](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff800798%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) when started via command prompt, started as admin:

- run `pnputil -e > C:\drivers.txt`

  [image]
- open the file drivers.txt and look which .inf file is associated with
  the driver you want to remove
- run `pnputil.exe -d oem<NUMBER>.inf`

This removes the driver correctly. If this is too complicated, you can use the tool [DriverStore Explorer [RAPR]](http://driverstoreexplorer.codeplex.com/)

[image]

Click on `enumerate`, select the driver in the list and click on `Delete Package`.

Comment: Sweet let me give it a try.

Comment: pnputil method worked, but instead of running pnputil command (didn't work) I used `pnputil.exe -flag` commands.